# Adding the value of two cells if two other cells have the same value

Tags: excel

I am  creating a tracking sheet for marketing items we have shipped. i have dropdown menus with all the applicable items, and the cell next to the dropdown will be how many we sent. i want to check if the input of the dropdowns is the same, and if so, add the numbers beside them and put the total on a separate sheet. For instance, cell c3 has a dropdown, so does f3. I want to see if c3 and f3 are the same, and if so, add c4 and f4 together elsewhere.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please review the [guidance on how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and consider editing your post. What have you tried so far? (Include code as appropriate). What is your specific error?

Answer (score 0):

So try

```
=IF(c3=F3,c4+F4,0)
```

That's the basic idea, now on a separate sheet, which we can call test, that becomes:

```
=IF(test!C3=test!F3,test!C4+test!F4,0)
```

[image]